# Is image column content in SQL Server binary or text encoded?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

When I do a select on an image column in SQL Server 2005, I see something like "0xFFD8FFE..." and I know a gif file is binary and starts with GIF89a...

So does SQL Server encode the column for display in Management Studio?

In C#, is the content saved using a byte array?

Comment: Are you sure the column's content is a GIF file? The `image` type means binary data, not necessarily a graphic image. And if it definitely is a GIF, what was the code that stored it? I seem to recall some database libraries that let you operate in terms of image files, and that actually prepended their own header so they could tell whether it was a GIF, JPG, etc., and then stripped their header off when you used that same library to read the image back out of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is hex representation of bytes array (basically 0x00 always indicates HEX format)

Regarding image column type:

> image Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1
>   (2,147,483,647) bytes.

Comment: Data was saved used byte array.